# google spreadsheet example code does not work

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I have several times tried to run first example code on this link on Google Spreadsheet: 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices

Code.gs:

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page')
      .evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

Page.html:

```
<?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>

<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>Please enjoy this helpful script.</p>

<?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
```

Stylesheet.html:

```
<style>
p {
  color: green;
}
</style>
```

JavaScript.html:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  alert('Page is loaded');
});
</script>
```

When I run the code, it says "Running script" then "Finished script", but I don't see the results. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

If you run the code from the code editor, you will not see results, you need to save a new version of your script and publish it as a web app that runs as the **User** acessing the web app, you can see the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps).